# Сокеты. Прием и отдача данных. Андроид

Tags: java, android, сокет

Есть клиент(андроид прил.) и Сервер(Ява прога). Сделал свой первый сокет и не очень в этом всем разбираюсь. На начала сделал прогу которая отправляет сообщения на сервер а тот принимает и пишет камандой `System.out.println(msg)`.
Тута все идеально но проблема в том что Когда я попытался сам самостоятельно прочитать на клиенте и отправить на сервере то ничего не вышло.
Вота кот сервера:

```
 try {
        while(true){
            mySock = new ServerSocket(5000);
            s = mySock.accept();
            in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(in);
            msg = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(msg);
            // Нижней код написал сам. Без этого код работал
            // пытаюсь прочитать данные
            pr = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            pr.write("send massenge");
            System.out.println("send massenge");

            pr.close();
            in.close();
            br.close();
            mySock.close();
            s.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

вот клиента(при каждом нажатии кнопки создается и запускается этот класс):

class MyTask extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        if (values[0].equals("0")){
            Toast.makeText(context , "true" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (values[0].equals("1")){
            Toast.makeText(context , "false" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(values[0] == null){
            Toast.makeText(context , "null" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context , values[0] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip , 5000);
            if (socket.isConnected()){
                publishProgress("0");
            }
            else {
                publishProgress("1");
            }
            pr = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            pr.write("message");
            // Нижней код написал сам. Без этого код работал
            // пытаюсь принять данные
            input = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            bf = new BufferedReader(input);
            String s = bf.readLine();
            publishProgress("server:".concat(s));


            bf.close();
            input.close();
            pr.close();
            socket.close();
            return "okey";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "ne okey";
        }
    }
}
```

При этом никаких ошибок. При первом нажатии выводиться Toast c надписью "true" , втарой же раз никакой реакции.

```
input = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
bf = new BufferedReader(input);
String s = bf.readLine();
publishProgress("server:".concat(s));
```

не выводится

Comment: У вас клиент ожидает строку (т.е. на конце будет окончание строки в виде `\n`), а вот на сервере вы отправляете без окончания: `pr.write("send massenge");`, т.е. типа `pr.println("send massenge");`. И добавьте после отправки команду flush: надо `pr.flush();` Либо включать autoFlush при инициализации `PrintWriter`

Comment: @lampa да все заработало. Еще один вопрос если readLine() читает одну строку до \n то как все строки прочитать?

Comment: или определенную строку

Comment: в цикле: `while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {}`

Comment: @lampa line должен быть массив или как?

Comment: Вы отправляете сообщение с несколькими строками. Цикл это сообщение прочитает построчно. Вам нужно просто собрать сообщение, например с помощью `StringBuilder`: `StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(); while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {build.append(line); } System.out.println(build);`

Comment: @lampa все заработало. Большое вам спасибо

Comment: я активно допиливаю свою библиотеку-обертку над сокетами: https://github.com/lampaa/ssocket можете глянуть, как она работает, если интересно.

Comment: @lampa я помню я ее хотел себе поключить) а зависимость в градле как прописать?

Comment: @lampa или только скачивать?

Comment: пока только скачать, но предупреждаю, я её даже пока нигде еще не использовал) Подпишитесь на проект, если интересно. Я скоро обновлю её.

Comment: @lampa Обязательно попробую либ.